# Proper way to setup SMTP server and Reverse DNS Records

Tags: smtp, domain-name-system

I have IIS 6 SMTP server running on 2003 box.

I am running a webserver (IIS) on the same system.

I want the SMTP server to deliver mail for my webserver.

I have it working fairly well - my only problem/confusion is getting a Reverse DNS record setup.

First, while this is all on the same machine, I believe it has been suggested that I use a separate IP address for the SMTP server.  I am doing this and have set DNS to point smtp.mydomain.com to this IP.  Good?

Now - I have to contact my ISP to have them make a Reverse DNS entry for my smtp server.

If the ip of smtp.mydomain.com is 1.2.3.4  - what is the proper request to make of my ISP?

Which (if any!) of the following do I want:

- 4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa  --->  1.2.3.4
- 4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa  --->  smtp.mydomain.com
- 4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa  --->  mydomain.com

Actually - would it be 4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa.mydomain.com?

Anyway, this is the only mail server I plan to set up on this server - so send for one domain.

If I am way off - please correct!

Thanks!

Comment: I wish I would have put this on ServerFault instead :(  If I 'vote to delete' - will it actually delete? (If so, I would gladly post on ServerFault instead.  If anyone has to power to remove it, go ahead...)

Answer (score 1):

the second one:

- 4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa ---> smtp.mydomain.com

if it was `4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa.mydomain.com`, you wouldn't need your ISP to do it